# How to get rid of deprecation warnings when providing backwards compatibility?

Tags: java, android, kotlin, deprecation-warning, android-lint

How one can get rid of linter deprecation warnings? For example, the annoying `NetworkInfo`:

```
warning: [deprecation] NetworkInfo in android.net has been deprecated
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to get rid of such deprecation warnings, when providing backwards compatibility,
one has to remove the `import`, to which one cannot apply `@SuppressWarnings("deprecation")`:

```
// import android.net.NetworkInfo;
```

And then use it's fully qualified class name `android.net.NetworkInfo` instead of `NetworkInfo`. The point is, that one can only apply `@SuppressWarnings("deprecation")` to methods, but not imports.

Answer (score 0):

You can consider using below annotation to remove warning message.

```
@SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
```

Comment: And how would you add this to an `import`?